# I cannot add functionality to the next button in my app. It should change the text every time it's pressed.

Tags: java, android, textview, android-button

I cannot add functionality to the next button in my app. It should change the text every time it's pressed. Though, in my case, what it does is change the text for once and then goes to sleep! What should I do? I searched the website but couldn't find any  way!

#### Java Code!

```
package com.dreamgoogle.gihf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Quotes extends Activity {

    ImageButton next;
    ImageButton previous;
    ImageButton copytext;
    TextView q;
    TextView nm;
    String[] str;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);
        varSet();

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int i = 0;
                i = i + 1;
                q.setText(str[i]);

            }

        });

    }

    private void varSet() {
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        copytext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.copy);
        q = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotes);
        str = new String[] {
                "In order to succeed, your desire for success should be greater than your fear of failure.",
                "A successful man is one who can lay a firm foundation with the bricks others have thrown at him.",
                "Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts.",
                "Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.",
                "Want Something? Go Get It!" };

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quotes, menu);
        return true;

    }

}
```

#### Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Quotes" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/h1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quotes"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="@string/h2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quotes"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/previous"
        android:src="@drawable/previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/next"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/copy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/copy"
        android:src="@drawable/copy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nm"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/quotes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/h3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If any of the answer helped you, then accept it / mark it as correct answer by clicking the tick mark at the left.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = 0;
    i = i + 1;
    q.setText(str[i]);
}
```

To

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    i = i + 1;
    q.setText(str[i]);
}
```

By declaring `i` again within the onClick() method, you hide the one in your Activity class. And since this method is called every time, `i` is always reset to 0, and hence your text will always be the value of `str[1]`

This is known as [variable hiding](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15).

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the iterator inside your onClick. What happens when you click is:

1) You create a new int with the value of 0;

2) 0 = 0 + 1;

3) you set q's text to str[1] each and every time.

Declare your iterator as a class variable for the OnClickListener or the whole Activity itself.